# 72h visa free transit BEIJING - HONG KONG - THAILAND - BEIJING - PARIS

Tags: visas, transit, china, visa-free-entry, pek

I am french and my student visa for China arrives soon to its expiration date and I only have one entry.
I am planning to go traveling to Hong Kong then Thailand and come back to Beijing (to find my stuffs), and finally go back to Paris 2 days after arriving to Beijing.

Am I eligible to 72-hour visa free transit in the Beijing Capital Airport ?

I already made some reasearch, and it seems that frontier security only check the first and third country you are going. In my case it would be Hong Kong and Beijing.

Do anyone who had similar situation can tell me ?

Comment: Did you purchase Thailand-Beijing-France as one ticket?

Comment: No one ticket is Beijing-Hong Kong-Bangkok-Beijing. The other one is Beijing-Paris.

Comment: Not pertinent on the date of the question, but for whoever is interested in 2018, the 72 hours has been changed to 144 hours.

Answer (score 2):

I just answered a very similar question [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60630/will-i-be-able-to-enjoy-the-72-hours-direct-transit-exemption-in-china/60643#60643), you will find it and the links provided there helpful I hope.

Your question is not completely clear to me, I assume you are currently in Beijing on a valid visa that permits you no more entries. Then you would travel Beijing-HK-Bangkok-Beijing on one ticket and Beijing-Paris on another ticket within the 72h.

In principle that should be possible but you have need to be able to convince immigration in Beijing (doable, they can check) and whoever checks you in in Bangkok (could be tricky) that you have a confirmed and seated ticket for the onward flight to Paris within 72h. In principle it does not matter if your booking is on different airlines, but it gives the lad in Bangkok a hard time checking wether you actually do have the other flight. You could try to get a boarding pass beforehand (online check-in).

Comment: That's my understanding, also.  You'll need to prove the ongoing flight but so long as you can do stuff it will work.